# Can't find source when debugging shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I want to debug my shader using visual studio graphics diagnostic tool. I did the instructions in the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DebuggingD3D11ShadersWithVS.html) and the graphics diagnostic captures frame. I click the play button next to shader in pixel history panel:

[image]

Now VS asks for some file temp.hlsl.4251_1.hlsl.

[image]

And when I cancel the dialog the editor shows source not found window instead of source code. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why this happens, but I know a workaround that works:

Simply rename the original shader file that corresponds to that pixel shader to whatever the dialog is asking, and then select it.

If you aren't reading your shaders from separate files (just converting strings from your C++ code), you'll obviously need to do that first.

Comment: I do this almost every day. Just make sure you rename it exactly to what it wants, which will look something like "myShader.hlsl.476_2.hlsl"